# Converting Traditional Chinese into Simplified Chinese in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, internationalization

A customer asked for a text conversion feature from traditional Chinese to simplified Chinese.

I did a little research and apparently it's the kind of thing that can be automated quite readily and Mac OS X even has a system wide service for doing this.. there seems to be something built into OS X to perform those changes, but I'm no expert at internationalization..

Does anybody know how to perform this miracle?

Best regards,

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the functionality you requested exists inside an app that Apple shipped with OS X--I don't know of any built-in functionality.

If you are trying to implement conversion, it looks like wikimedia has some code that might do what you want, but you'll have to convert it from PHP:

http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classZhConverter.html

Also, it may not be just a matter of converting the characters, although that's most of it... there are also phrases that are different in mainland Chinese (simplified characters) and other places (traditional characters).

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like it's non-trivial and probably best left alone unless you speak Chineses and can make sure the solution works as expected.